# reaching Gmail SMTP daily limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, smtp, gmail

In one of my Rails applications I'm sending emails through the Gmail SMTP server and everything just works, mails are not going to spam and so on ... But there's one thing that concerns me, the **500messages/day** limit the SMTP has, currently I'm over 350/day. I didn't find any official Google page where they talk about the subject, just blog posts that seems to be reliable. **Then my question is** what do you suggest me in order to be able to send more than 500messages/day? I would love to keep using the Gmail SMTP.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: if you have a google apps account you can use smtp-relay.google.com

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't use GMail for what it wasn't built for. It wasn't designed as a mass-email system, although Google definitely has the firepower to do this.

Instead, perhaps use something like [SendGrid](http://sendgrid.com) to send your emails. SendGrid is *designed* for this and is just as easy (actually, probably **easier**) to set up with than GMail.

Comment: This is very interesting! Have you used this before?

Comment: I'm using SendGrid right now on my day job's work application. It works perfect for our needs (sending out 3.5 million emails a month)

Answer (score 2):

You can consider using more than one gmail account to access the smtp server, however you may have problems with ip limits (couldn't find anything on their docs about it). Another option is performing dns mx lookups yourself and reproducing your own smtp server by directly delivering the messages to the user's emails - but that can increase the odds of you being tagged as a spammer as your ip is not whitelisted as sender.

I think the best way is to create another gmail account and trying to reroute your connection to use it when one of the accounts reaches the daily limit. A vpn connection can solve that for you.

Comment: Try and see if a second account solves your problem.. A vpn can tunnel your connection through another server machine (a router running DD-WRT or OpenWRT for example.. or even a university computer). You don't really need a vpn, you can use a simple proxy for that matter. I am just worried that google may limit the daily number of email you can send from an unique ip - even if it comes from multiple accounts. A vpn or proxy will mask your ip, solving that problem.