# Gmail as SMTP server on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I saw Heroku has a plugin called Sendgrid. It lets you send 200 emails a day for free. My questions is If I use Gmail to send mails from an app on heroku, Can I send more than 200 emails daily, for free?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gmail has a 500 email per day limit.

related: [reaching Gmail SMTP daily limit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929457/reaching-gmail-smtp-daily-limit)

And as also is mentioned on that question, you can use multiple gmail accounts and rotate them to raise your limits.

Comment: 500 questions? Did you mean email?