# Using gmail for SMTP

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am using a gmail account (personalized to our company domain name) to send outbound emails for our application, for things like password resets, contact forms, newsletters etc.

Is there any issues to be aware of? For example, I read that there is a maximum number of allowed daily gmail emails, but I can't find what the value is and what happens as you reach this amount...

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3929457/reaching-gmail-smtp-daily-limit

Answer (score 4):

I *suspect* that [this article on sending limits](https://www.google.com/support/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=166852) is what you're looking for:

> Google has a number of sending limits in place to prevent abuse of our system, and to help fight spam. If one of your mail accounts reaches an abuse limit, the account will be temporarily unable to send mail.
>
> Each Google Apps account can currently send to 500 external recipients per day. Google Apps for Business and Education users can send to 2000 external recipients per day. The email addresses can be distributed among the To:, Cc:, and Bcc: fields. Administrators can contact all user accounts within the domain by adding everyone in the domain to an email list.

(Disclaimer: I work for Google, but this answer is solely my personal opinion. It does not reflect any "inside knowledge" and I've never worked with the Gmail team.)